# Why does my program not work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I got a simple program that get some input from the user and the computer in a simple  Rock scissor paper game. I am supposed to compare the input from the user and then compare with the output of the

Everything is fine, the variable computer shows the correct output but when I assign to variable cs which is supposed to take the first character  of computer, it always shows the same output as the player ps, therefore the result is always a tie, which is wrong.

Can any of you guys tell me why and how should I resolve this?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
  Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Complete Java Script Course</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Yuan">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="output">Complete Java Script Course</div>
  <script>
      var output = document.getElementById("output");
   var player = prompt("Do you Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?")
   var ps = player.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
   
   var win = false;
   var computer = Math.random();
   if(computer < 0.34){computer ="Rock";}
   else if (computer < 0.67){computer ="Paper";}
   else{computer= "Scissors";}
   var cs = computer.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
   console.log(computer);
   var html="";
   
   if (cs=ps){
    html+="Its a tie!";}
   else{
   
    if(ps=="R"){
      if(cs=="S"){win=true;} 
     
    }
    else if(ps=="P"){
     if(cs=="R"){win=true;}
    }
    else{
     if(cs=="P"){win=true;}
    }
    if(win){
     html += "Player Wins!";
    } else{
        html+= "Computer Wins!";
    }
   }
   
   output.innerHTML = "Player Vs Computer<br>"+ player+" "+ "vs" +" "+computer+"<br>Result:"+" "+html;
    
  </script>
   

   

   

   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `=` is the _assignment_ operator …

Comment: also in your first if the else condition should check if computer is greater than 0.34 and smaller than 0.67

Comment: @LelioFaieta That's not needed. Coz it won't get there. `:)` The OP has used `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare not assign. Use `==` or better `===`:

```
if (cs == ps) {
```

When you assign, you already setting it up to tie. Here's your fully corrected code
**snippet:**

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var player = prompt("Do you Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?")
var ps = player.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
var win = false;
var computer = Math.random();
if (computer < 0.34) {
  computer = "Rock";
} else if (computer < 0.67) {
  computer = "Paper";
} else {
  computer = "Scissors";
}
var cs = computer.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
console.log(computer);
var html = "";
if (cs == ps) {
  html += "Its a tie!";
} else {
  if (ps == "R") {
    if (cs == "S") {
      win = true;
    }
  } else if (ps == "P") {
    if (cs == "R") {
      win = true;
    }
  } else {
    if (cs == "P") {
      win = true;
    }
  }
  if (win) {
    html += "Player Wins!";
  } else {
    html += "Computer Wins!";
  }
}
output.innerHTML = "Player Vs Computer<br>" + player + " " + "vs" + " " + computer + "<br>Result:" + " " + html;
```

```html
<div id="output">Complete Java Script Course</div>
```

Comment: @Matt I am unable to find any other problems with it. (Even though some syntax is wrong).

Comment: Sure, because you haven't provided a snippet. Note that SY Lim's snippet does not even run without error.

Comment: JSBin? Why haven't you shared it here?

Comment: @Matt Doing it now... Sorry forgot to include it. `:(`

Comment: You can also convert you answer into a Stack Overflow code snippet.

Comment: And since you have done that now successfully, you can remove the duplicate code above. :-)

Answer (score -1):

The condition `if (cs=ps)` will always return true as this is an assignment and not comparison. Make it `if (cs===ps)` or `if (cs==ps)`

Also, refer the below links if you were not aware of this concept

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Answer (score -3):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
  Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Complete Java Script Course</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Yuan">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="output">Complete Java Script Course</div>
  <script>
      var output = document.getElementById("output");
   var player = prompt("Do you Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?")
   var ps = player.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
   
   var win = false;
   var computer = Math.random();
   if(computer < 0.34){computer ="Rock";}
   else if (computer < 0.67){computer ="Paper";}
   else{computer= "Scissors";}
   var cs = computer.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
   console.log(computer);
   var html="";
   
   if (cs=ps){
    html+="Its a tie!";}
   else{
   
    if(ps=="R"){
      if(cs=="S"){win=true;} 
     
    }
    else if(ps=="P"){
     if(cs=="R"){win=true;}
    }
    else{
     if(cs=="P"){win=true;}
    }
    if(win){
     html += "Player Wins!";
    } else{
        html+= "Computer Wins!";
    }
   }
   
   output.innerHTML = "Player Vs Computer<br>"+ player+" "+ "vs" +" "+computer+"<br>Result:"+" "+html;
    
  </script>
   

   

   

   
 </body>
</html>
```

Dear its working .i tested please again check

Comment: It won't. Coz your aren't comparing.